# RecyclerView behavoir: specific row customize is duplicated on other row (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm new in Android dev and now porting my iOS app.
Trying to make pretty complex RecyclerView, but at some moment behavoir of the specific row is duplicated on other row after notifyDataSetChanged() method.

[There are three rows with same ViewType in first part of RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9HMq.png)

Each of them has TextView and EditText widgets, that I'm populating in CustomViewHolder class.

First and second rows should work as always: when I'm click in EditText - the keyboard opens. But third row EditText's focus should initiate dialog alert. Everything works great until reload of adapter's DataSet. After DataSet reload the first row's EditText also begins to open the dialog alert instead of normal opening of the keyboard.

Looks like I'm missing something and somehow referencing to the same object when customizing my rows. Here's my adapter code (simplified):

```
class NewRequestsRecyclerAdapter(val context: Context, val parameters:ArrayList<NewRequestsFragment.ParameterCell>,val delegate:NewRequestProtocol?): RecyclerView.Adapter<NewRequestsRecyclerAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

enum class RowType {
    Header,Parameter
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    // count logic
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent : ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val cellForRow = when (RowType.values()[viewType]) {
        RowType.Header -> layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_header,parent,false)
        RowType.Parameter -> layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_parameter_new_requests,parent,false)
     }

    return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow, RowType.values()[viewType])
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    // Here's ItemViewType logic ...
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindMenu(position)
}

inner class CustomViewHolder(val cellView: View, val type:RowType): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(cellView) {
    fun bindMenu(row:Int) {

        when (type) {
            RowType.Header -> {
                val nameView = cellView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.headerName)
                // other logic to populate Header views
            }
            RowType.Parameter -> {
                val nameView = cellView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.paramName)
                val editText = cellView.findViewById<EditText(R.id.paramEditText)
                nameView.text = parameters[row-1].name
                editText.apply {
                    hint = parameters[row-1].placeholder
                    when (parameters[row-1].type) {
                        NewRequestsFragment.PartsCellType.Name -> {
                            setText(delegate?.currentItem?.name)
                        }
                        NewRequestsFragment.PartsCellType.Number -> {
                            setText(delegate?.currentItem?.number)
                        }
                        NewRequestsFragment.PartsCellType.StateType-> {
                            setText(delegate?.currentItem?.state)
                            showSoftInputOnFocus = false
                            setOnFocusChangeListener { view, changed ->
                                if (changed) {
                                    inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
                                    delegate?.showStateDialog()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I know to resolve that problem I can show alert with button, but I would like to know why my code leads to this behavior.
Could you please guide me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problem with a `RecyclerView` where one item mysteriously takes on the attributes or behavior of another item is usually due to not resetting the view holder.

You are defining the behavior of your view holders when they are created, so, the first time, all view holders are created and behave appropriately. When things change, the view holders are *reused* and not recreated. As a result, things can get mixed up such as getting a dialog opened when the keyboard should show.

To correct this, reset the view holder when it is bound to behave the way you want.